# Class Property Not be included as sqlite database column

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I have one entity class as

```
  public class someclass
  {
      public string property1 {get; set;}
      public string property2 {get; set;}
      public string property3 {get; set;}
  }
```

and using sqlite connection class obj DB I am creating the table

```
  Db.CreateTableAsync<someclass>().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

What I want to achieve is, I don't want sqlite to create column in the table for `property3`. Is there any way to achieve this?

I am using SQLiteAsync library for windows store apps.

Comment: I think you can't because there's no method to create table using column names. Right now we have just a method which passes the class name(s) as argument.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the `Ignore` attribute:

```
public class someclass
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public string property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: And how do you define relationship between two tables? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539683/relational-sqlite-on-windows-rt

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It's 2016 and your answer has definitely helped me.

Answer (score 12):

As chue x has said previously, you should use the Ignore attribute, but I figured I would give a bit more information as to what all the attributes do since it seems like some information that would be useful in this thread.

Here's a quick summary of the types of attributes available for use (for those of you that don't like reading and just want to know quickly):

**PrimaryKey** - This property is the primary key of the table. Only single-column primary keys are supported.

**AutoIncrement** - This property is automatically generated by the database upon insert.

**Indexed** - This property should have an index created for it.

**MaxLength** - If this property is a String then MaxLength is used to specify the varchar max size. The default max length is 140.

**Ignore** - This property will not be in the table.

If you want to know more, check out my more in depth blog post on these attributes:

http://lukealderton.com/blog/posts/2016/august/sqlite-attributes-and-what-they-do.aspx

Comment: Also `PrimaryKey` has hidden `Indexed` inside, meaning all primary keys are indexed by default and you don't need to use both properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ignore attribute as in this code:

```
        [ObservableProperty][property: PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("ara_id")] public int ara_id;
    [ObservableProperty][property: Ignore] public StareAratare ara_stare;
```