# Relational SQLite on Windows RT

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, foreign-keys, windows-store-apps

i am using [SQLite for Windows Runtime](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e) but i dont see any way to define relationships between tables. Is this feature supported in SQLite for WinRT?

If not, are there any alternative solutions for relational local database for Windows RT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database engine itself supports relationships.  One way is to specify the foreign keys when creating the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo(
Id integer primary key autoincrement not null ,
...
)

CREATE TABLE Bar(
Id integer primary key autoincrement not null,
FooId integer not null REFERENCES Foo (Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
...
)
```

I believe each db connection has to also enable foreign keys by executing the following pragma:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

In terms of the available ORMs, I guess that depends. I have only used [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net), so I can only speak about that.  As far as I know, foreign keys are currently not a supported feature for SQL-Net. You have to manually manage the relationships.

For example, lets say your `Foo` object has a reference in it to a `Bar` object.

For creating the tables, you cannot use the SQLite-Net table creation methods. You have to use SQL to create the tables along with the relationships.

Also, when you use SQL-Net to load the `Foo` object, the related `Bar` object will not automatically be loaded. You will need to make a second SQL-Net call to load the `Bar` object.

Comment: Its unfortunate, but thanx anyway :) btw, i checked their GIT project hosting, and according to some last commits (3 months old at this time) there is some effort to implement this.